# Using Postgres 'serial' in Django (other than primary key)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have created a custom field for my model, `BigSerialField` as below.

```
class BigSerialField(models.Field):

description = 'Big Serial of Postgres'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BigSerialField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def deconstruct(self):
    name, path, args, kwargs = super(BigSerialField, self).deconstruct()
    return name, path, args, kwargs

def db_type(self, connection):
    return 'bigserial'

def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
    if value is None:
        raise Exception('Big Serial cannot be null!')
    return int(value)

def get_prep_value(self, value):
    return None

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    return None

def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection)


def to_python(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value

    if value is None:
        raise Exception('Big Serial cannot be null!')

    return int(value)
```

This raises an error, because now the ORM tries to pass `null` to the field while saving. Postgres requires the `DEFAULT` keyword instead. However, when I try to send in `'default'` instead of `None` in `get_db_prep_save`, then Postgres raises an error because it interprets `'default'` as string rightly.

So, what's the way in Django to send in the `DEFAULT` keyword to Postgres?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem and am wondering if you were able to solve it